# @Published requires willSet to fire

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a class:

```
final class LocationManager: NSObject, ObservableObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
  let objectWillChange = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()
  private let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

  @Published var status: String? {
    willSet { objectWillChange.send() }
  }
  @Published var location: CLLocation? {
    willSet { objectWillChange.send() }
  }

// ...other code
  }
```

And then I have a view that observes this class:

```
struct MapView: UIViewRepresentable {
  @ObservedObject var lm = LocationManager()

  // ...other view code
}
```

Everything works fine and the view updates when the published property changes. However, if I remove the `willSet { objectWillChange.send() }` then the view that observes an instance of `LocationManager` does not update when the published location changes. Which brings me to my question: I thought that by putting `@Published` next to a `var` that any `@ObservedObject` will invalidate the current view when the published property changes, essentially a default `objectWillChange.send()` implementation but this doesn't seem to be happening. Instead I have to manually call the update. Why is that?

Comment: *By default an ObservableObject synthesizes an objectWillChange publisher that emits the changed value before any of its @Published properties changes.* I think you don't need to declare your own `objectWillChange`.

Comment: Thats what I thought too but if I remove the `objectWillChange.send()` then view updates won't happen

Comment: I mean you can remove `let objectWillChange = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple documentation states:

> By default an ObservableObject synthesizes an objectWillChange
>   publisher that emits the changed value before any of its @Published
>   properties changes.

This means you don't need to declare your own `objectWillChange`. You can just remove `objectWillChange` from your code including the following line:

```
let objectWillChange = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()
```

Answer (score 3):

You're doing too much work. It looks like you're trying to *write* ObservableObject. You don't need to; it already exists. The whole point is that ObservableObject is *already* observable, automatically. Here's a non-SwiftUI example:

```
final class Thing: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    @Published var status: String?
}
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var storage = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    let thing = Thing()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.thing.objectWillChange
            .sink {_ in print("will change")}.store(in: &self.storage)
        self.thing.$status
            .sink { print($0) }.store(in: &self.storage)
    }
    @IBAction func doButton (_ sender:Any) {
        self.thing.status = (self.thing.status ?? "") + "x"
    }
}
```

The thing to notice is that, although the observable object contains no code at all, it is emitting a signal every time its `status` property is set, *before* the property changes. Then the `status` property itself emits a signal, namely its new value.

The same thing happens in SwiftUI.